# VS2008: Running xsd.exe on schema file gives XMLSchema:datetime is not declared

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xsd.exe

I have a an XSD that looks like this (roughly)

```
<xs:schema id="Appointment" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Record.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified"
attributeFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Record.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/Record.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="Record" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Record">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="TimeStart" type="xs:datetime" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="TimeEnd" type="xs:datetime" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I try to generate classes from it using the xsd.exe from VS2008 I get string fields instead of date fields, and a warning that

```
Schema validation warning: Type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:datetime' is not declared. Line 13, position 9.
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bah, nevermind.

Was case sensitivity issue.

The correct form to use was

```
xs:dateTime
```

instead of

```
xs:datetime
```